Rotating SSL certificate on unbounded Kafka source in Flink application
I have long running Flink job, that is reading from Kafka source. Kafka broker requires client authorization. Key, certificate and ca certificate are provided in PEM format. Path to these are passed during kafka source instantiation.
Flink is running in application mode, using flink k8s operator
Once certificate expires, jobmanager fails to update topics metadata (as seen in log from kafka source enumerator) and taskmanagers failed to connect to broker (which is expected). However, none of them restart, they keep running. This is most apparent on Flink dashboard, where not even job status changes.
JobManager message:
WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.internals.AdminMetadataManager [] - [AdminClient clientId=KafkaSource--5194103613512110967-enumerator-admin-client] Metadata update failed due to authentication error
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: Failed to process post-handshake messages
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
...
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!

Taskmanager message:
ERROR org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient                       [] - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 1001 (kafka/172.18.0.3:9092) failed authentication due to: Failed to process post-handshake messages

Broker message
INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=1001] Failed authentication with /172.18.0.7 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)

My goal is to find a way to automatically rotate certificates for kafka clients, without manual intervention. Brief stop of data pipeline is acceptable. I already have process for retrieving new certificates (I have my own CA), so this is not subject of question.
In order to create level of indirection, i have converted PEM files into PKCS12 keystores in a hope that kafka client will reread their content upon connection retry. I have launched sidecar, that was monitoring PEM certificates. Upon new certificate publish, this sidecar generated new keystore with updated certificates with same name in shared volume. I have successfully verified, that keystore contained updated certificate with prolonged validity. This however did not change anything. It seems kafka client has cached certificate content on first read.
I wanted to restart flink job, but job itself is not failing. No restart strategy is invoked. I cannot hook into any shutdown sequence or retry mechanism
